# REST - SparkJava not update object JSON when I use GET

Tags: java, json, rest, spark-java

I have problem with update object json after change on page where I  get text. In below my code and response API.

**Response API:**

```
[
    { "title": "„Jak wykorzystać media i nowoczesne technologie w edukacji?” – warsztaty dla nauczycieli",
      "url": "http://www.up.krakow.pl/uniwersytet/aktualnosci/1772-jak-wykorzystac-media-i-nowoczesne-technologie-w-edukacji-warsztaty-dla-nauczycieli"
    }
]
```

**Java Service:**

```
public class NewsService implements NewsServiceInterface {
    private Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.up.krakow.pl/uniwersytet/aktualnosci").get();
    private Elements links = doc.select("div.page-header");
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> store = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public NewsService() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public List<News> getNews() {
        List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element element : links) {
            String title = element.select("a[href]").text(); // get only text
            String url = "http://www.up.krakow.pl" + element.select("a[href]").attr("href"); // get only link
            if (!store.containsKey(title)) {
                store.put(title, url);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : store.entrySet()) {
            newsList.add(new News(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return Lists.reverse(newsList);
    }
}
```

Java Controller:

```
public class NewsController {
  private static final String API_CONTEXT = "/api/v1";
    public NewsController(final NewsService newsService) {
        get(API_CONTEXT + "/getnews", (request, response) -> {          
            return newsService.getNews();
        }, json());
}
```

**Java POJO:**

```
public class News implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("counterAllNews")
    private String counterAllNews;

    public News() {
    }

    public News(String title, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

// getter and setter

}
```

**Java Main:**

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            new NewsController(new NewsService());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Java JSON:**

```
public class JsonUtil {
    public static String toJson(Object object) {
        return new Gson().toJson(object);
    }


    public static ResponseTransformer json() {
        return JsonUtil::toJson;
    }
}
```

Where is problem? The JSON is update if I restart jetty server. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you always get the same results when repeatedly calling your service? And you expect to get changing entries because the original source where you fetch them changes?

This is because you read that information from *www.up.krakow.pl/uniwersytet/aktualnosci* only once when the `NewsService` is instantiated. And that is done only once in your main method:

```
new NewsController(new NewsService());
```

Change the `NewsService` implementation, so that you refetch the news data on every get:

```
public class NewsService implements NewsServiceInterface {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> store = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public NewsService() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public List<News> getNews() {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.up.krakow.pl/uniwersytet/aktualnosci").get();
        Elements links = doc.select("div.page-header");
        List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element element : links) {
            String title = element.select("a[href]").text(); // get only text
            String url = "http://www.up.krakow.pl" + element.select("a[href]").attr("href"); // get only link
            if (!store.containsKey(title)) {
                store.put(title, url);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : store.entrySet()) {
            newsList.add(new News(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return Lists.reverse(newsList);
    }
}
```

This is just a fix for getting always the same values. Depending of how often your service is called, this might lead to lots of requests to the backend server you are querying. In this case you should add some kind of cache which will for example only fetch new data from the back when the last one is too old. But that's a different story.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. I changed code and I will  inform about result